# Issue in creating Multiple Avro Flume Sink in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, flume, hadoop-streaming, flume-ng

I need to connect multiple Flume sinks with Spark Streaming
 this is my flume file :

```
agent1.sinks.sink1a.type = avro
agent1.sinks.sink1a.hostname = localhost
agent1.sinks.sink1a.port = 9091

agent1.sinks.sink1b.type = avro
agent1.sinks.sink1b.hostname = localhost
agent1.sinks.sink1b.port = 9092
```

**But only 9091 port is connecting 9092 is not able to connect**

Here is my spark code to create multiple Flume Streams :

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(20))

val rawLines = FlumeUtils.createStream(ssc,"localhost", 9091)
val rawLines1 = FlumeUtils.createStream(ssc,"localhost", 9092)


val lines = rawLines.map{record => {
                (new String(record.event.getBody().array()))}}

val lines1 = rawLines1.map{record1 => {
                (new String(record1.event.getBody().array()))}}

val lines_combined = lines.union(lines1)

val words = lines_combined.flatMap(_.split(" "))
```

What am I doing wrong ?.Any help regarding the same would be great.

Comment: I really suggest you to use a different solution for that. If it is possible to handle this with a Kafka cluster. Due to this solution will create a lot of overhead in Spark processing. Set up all your sinks in a Kafka Topic with a good amount of partitions it will help you for handle the data and handle Spark reading.

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim : ok, Iwill try using Kafka also, but for the above problem is there no solution available ? Does it mean Flume can't create  multiple avro  sinks ?